# Highcharts-ng rangeSelector doesn't highlight selected button

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

The following cofiguration selects the range correctly, but the button doesn't get highlighted:

```
rangeSelector: {selected: 3}
```

The same configuration works fine without angular. Is there something specific to highcharts-ng that I'm missing? Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcf2h0rm/18/).

[image]

```
rangeSelector: {
selected: 3,
enabled: true,
buttons: [{ type: 'day',count: 1, text: '1d' }, 
    {type: 'day', count: 2, text: '2d' }, 
    {type: 'day', count: 7, text: '1 wk' }, 
    {type: 'day',count: 14, text: '2 wk'},
    {type: 'month', count: 1, text: '1m'}, 
    { type: 'year', count: 1, text: '1y'}, 
    {type: 'all',  text: 'All'}]
```

}

Comment: Since it is [working fine in Highstock itself](http://jsfiddle.net/2qh1Lq5v/), then it looks like highcharts-ng error. As a workaround you could set `allButtonsEnabled: true,` - https://jsfiddle.net/nebtfcm5/

Comment: Thank you Kacper, it's a nice workaround. I also found another workaround - looping through "highcharts-button" after the chart is fully loaded, and clicking on the correct button $('g[class="highcharts-button"]').each(function (index, item) {if (index == 4) {$(item).trigger('click');}}